# Formatting date from d-mmm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-d in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

What's the best way to format below date in angular 2 using datepipe?

I'm trying to format a date with the following format: d-mmm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-d

For example, from 1-Nov-2019 to 2019-11-1 or 15-Dec-2018 to 2018-12-15

I must accomplish this using date pipe built in functions.

Comment: you should already know how to output `yyyy-mm-d` with a pipe, if the problem comes to "how to convert a string to a Date object", you should either choose a library like moment.js or start to analyze all the possible values of your input so you can create your own parse method just for your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
const date = new Date()
  .toISOString()
  .slice(0, 10)
  .split("-")
  .reverse();
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
...

@Component({
  providers: [DatePipe],
  ...
})

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) { }

// use the following where you need
this.datePipe.transform(yourDate, 'yyyy-mm-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 pipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
 todayWithPipe = null;
 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.todayWithPipe = this.pipe.transform(Date.now(), 'yyyy.MM.dd');
 }}

<h3> Date in YYYY.MM.DD Format </h3>
<p>{{ todayWithPipe }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `Date` class in JS?

```js
const d = new Date("1-Nov-2019");

function transform(d) {
  return `${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth()+1}-${d.getDate()}`
}

console.log(transform(d));
```

Or attach this function into the `Date` class like so:

```js
Date.prototype.transform = function() {
  return `${this.getFullYear()}-${this.getMonth()+1}-${this.getDate()}`
}

console.log(d.transform());
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do the trick:

```
{{ myDate | date :'yyyy-mm-d' }}
```

Full doc right here: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment.js library and change your date in the ts and then display it on the template

```
moment(yourDate).format('yyyy-mm-d')
```

you can format the date in the template

```
{{ yourDate | date :'yyyy-mm-d' }}
```